# Firebase app distribution testers auto-assignment

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I am new to Firebase. I have a configured app distribution flow in the Firebase but I have to manually add the existing tester group to each new build. How can I config the tester auto-assignment for every new build?

Answer (score 0):

For Android: You can use [Gradle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle) to distribute your apps to testers

For iOS: You can use [Fastlane](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-fastlane) to distribute your apps to testers

In both these distribution flows, you can config the testers and tester groups you'd like to distribute to.